# Verify mocks in Assert.Multiple

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

Is it possible to verify a method call in an `Assert.Multiple` block alongside other calls to `Assert`?

My current solution does not call the assert on `SomeProperty`, when the method call to `MyMethod` does not verify.
And the only way to get close to what I want would be to move the call to `myInterfaceMock.Verify` to the end, but that does no longer work when there are multiple method calls to verify.

```cs
var mInterfaceMock = new Mock<IMyInterface>()
  .Setup(x => x.MyMethod())
  .Verifiable();
var systemUnderTest = new MyClass(myInterfaceMock.Object);

systemUnderTest.MethodToTest();

Assert.Multiple(() => {
  myInterfaceMock.Verify();
  Assert.That(systemUnderTest.SomeProperty, Is.True);
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The verify will throw its own exception that the assertion block wont know how to handle. That is why when the verify fails nothing gets invoked after it.

The notes in documentation also states

> The test will be terminated immediately if any exception is thrown that is not handled. An unexpected exception is often an indication that the test itself is in error, so it must be terminated. If the exception occurs after one or more assertion failures have been recorded, those failures will be reported along with the terminating exception itself.

Reference [Multiple Asserts](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/assertions/multiple-asserts.html#notes)

Consider the following approach

```
//...

Assert.Multiple(() => {
  Assert.That(() => myInterfaceMock.Verify(), Throws.Nothing);
  Assert.That(systemUnderTest.SomeProperty, Is.True);
});
```

If the verify throws an exception then it will be handled by its own assertion.

Answer (score 0):

If your `MethodToTest()` does not return anything they I'd recommend just verifying if the method run, as you're trying to do with the assert, but I'd recommend doing something like this:

```
mInterfaceMock.Verify(x => x.MethodToTest(), Times.Once);
```

just specifying the times it has had to run, without it inside of an assertion

Comment: This approach does not allow me to Assert multiple things and see the result of all failing asserts, when the test fails.